# How to hack jQuery Autocomplete plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery's Autocomplete plugin, and the list of suggestions are generated dynamically. I want to get rid of the filtering provided by the autocomplete function, i.e i want to load all the data coming from the backend. 
code that i am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#search_box").autocomplete("myscript/index");
}

<input type='input' id='search_box' />
```

PHP backend code (symfony 1.4) 
At action:

```
$s = $request->getParameter("p");
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(DataSkillPeer::SKILLNAME, $s);
$data_array = array();
$data_skill_array = DataSkillPeer::doSelect($c);
foreach($data_skill_array as $arrays)
{
   $data_array[] = $arrays; 
}
$this->display_data = json_decode($data_array, true);
```

At view:

```
<?php if(!empty($display_data)): ?>
  <?php foreach($display_data as $da): ?>
        <?php echo $da."\n"; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the data is send from the myscript.php file, and i want to load all the data comming from the backend, example if i type j, then the my backend generates java, javascript, jquery, ejb. i want all this data to be displayed without being filtered by autocomplete function like suggestions. is there any way i can hack the autocomplete function to do so without loosing the UI effect it provides.

Comment: The autocomplete plugin just spits out what you supply from your datasource. Doesn't that happen for you?

Comment: @john yeah it worked for me but i want it to show all the data array comming from the backend other than filtering the response array. just like suggestion.

Comment: So what happens now? Doesn't it show all the data your PHP file sends it? How does it filter?

Comment: @john now it returns all the array, and works fine but it filters that return array and shows it and dont display all data. like example my return array is "java beans, javabean, enterprise java beans" and the autocomplete filters array and shows "java beans, javabean". and i want to show all the data comming form the server.

Comment: you probably have a limit set. Is that the only bit of code you're using?

Comment: @john, yeah actually the sorting based on key word is done at the backend php script. and hence i want to stop the sorting of data done at frontend and only load the data as it is and fill the textbox on selecting or clicking it..

Comment: You might want to look at what your script is returning. I use autocomplete and it doesn't do any filtering on it's own unless you tell it to

Comment: @john script is returning correctly, but the autocomplete is not showing all data returned...it dose as it looks for the array an the key we pressed. like if we have an array like "['i','love','css','jquery','java','c']" and is passed to the autocomplete as parameter. then on pressing c it will return css and c and not all the data array.

Comment: This is what I use : http://pastebin.com/yB4JErt2 It does not filtering and simply shows what is given to it. You can ignore the `open` and `close` methods.

Comment: @john actually it is not firing the key event every time thats the problem i think, as if i press a the backend returns [asp, asp.net, actionscript]. but if i click s then it wont fire a query to the server and take the data from the exesting array and show [asp, asp.net]

Comment: hmm, I can't do much unless you can put up a demo or something.

Comment: ah the cache was getting in the way? no worries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution without hacking the autocomplete plugin, as i saw that when i clicked "a" in textbox it queried the backend php script and returned the array ["asp", "asp.net", "actionscript"] and on clicking "s" it didnt fire the backend script as it was taking the data from the cache. hence set the property as `{cacheLength: 0}` and it worked. 
Thanks every one for helping me out and your time. and special tanks @JohnP.

Comment: if there is any other alternate way please post!